# how to restart Cordova app after it is killed

Tags: android, cordova, service, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I am using a plugin for background service in my android cordova app

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode

but my app seems to crash/freeze or killed after 5-6 hours, is there any way i can restart my application after it is killed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have a workaround .. The app stops in the background when the Phone goes to sleep .. so I had to make sure, the phone doesn't go to sleep ..

So i used power management plugin together with Background mode plugin.. and it works well..

Comment: Hi can u explain about your solution and say example because  i have same issue?

Comment: you can use PowerManagement plugin to avoid phone going to sleep https://github.com/Viras-/cordova-plugin-powermanagement